# ¿Existe un convenio o norma para la modificación de parámetros mutables pasados como argumentos a una función?

Tags: python, funciones, lista

Investigando este tema he encontrado la siguiente advertencia:

> ADVERTENCIA.
>
> En general, se espera que una función que recibe
> parámetros mutables, no los modifique, ya que si se los modifica se
> podría perder información valiosa.
>
> En el caso en que por una decisión de diseño o especificación se
> modifiquen los parámetros recibidos, esto debe estar claramente
> documentado, dentro de las postcondiciones.

¿Existe una norma o estándar al respecto o esta advertencia es una opinión del autor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como norma general, una función no debería tener ningún efecto colateral y devolver un resultado basado únicamente en los valores de los argumentos de entrada.

Además de perder información, es también importante conservar inmutables las variables y objetos que vayan a ser compartidos (eg: programación concurrente).

Es por ello que, antes de modificar un argumento, la recomendación es hacer una copia y trabajar sobre la copia.

Veamos algunos casos:

Como caso conocido de argumento mutable sería pasar una lista:

```
lst = [2,1,3]

def fun(lst):
   lst.sort()
   return lst

fun(lst)    
print(lst)  # -> [1,2,3]
```

Al ordenar la lista hemos perdido el orden original. De modo similar, si alteramos algún elemento perderíamos la lista original.

La recomendación sería usar una copia. En el caso de listas, la función `sorted` ya nos crea una copia:

```
lst = [2,1,3]

def fun(lst):
   return sorted(lst)

lst2 = fun(lst)
print(lst)  # -> [2,1,3]
```

En el caso de argumentos que tengan valores por defecto, se considera mala práctica usar listas como valores por defecto. Veamos el motivo:

```
def suma(lst=[]):
    lst.append(sum(lst))
    return lst
```

Si probamos:

```
>>> suma()
[0]
>>> suma()
[0,0]
>>> suma([1,2,3])
[1,2,3,6]
>>> suma()
[0,0,0]
```

El propio valor por defecto muta, lo que acaba siendo incontrolable. La recomendación es no usar nunca valores mutables en valores por defecto. La idea sería algo así:

```
def suma(lst=None):
    if lst is None:
        lst = []
    lst.append(sum(lst))
    return lst
```

Por último, habría que explicar cuándo es admisible que mute algún argumento. En general, sería en casos en los que se produce un "cambio de estado" durante la ejecución de la función. Es un modo de señalar a otros procesos que ha habido un cambio con el fin de que puedan responder adecuadamente.

Como recomendación, implementar los estados como "propiedades" (`properties`) para tener mejor control de cuándo y cómo se puede cambiar de estado.

Un ejemplo:

```
class Data:
    def __init__(self):
        self._data = []
        self._empty = True

    @property
    def empty(self):
        return self._empty

    @property
    def data(self):
        return self._data

    def append(self, x):
        self._data.append(x)
        self._empty = False

dat = Data()

def fun(dat, x=None):
    if x is not None:
        dat.append(x)

print(f"Vacío={dat.empty}")  # True
fun(dat)
print(f"Vacío={dat.empty}")  # True
fun(dat, 1)
print(f"Vacío={dat.empty}")  # False
```

Nuestra instancia de `Data` únicamente permite cambiar su valor a través del método `append` desde donde se controla el estado `empty`. De este modo, cuando la función mute la instancia, cambiará el estado `empty` de `True` a `False`.

Comment: No entiendo por qué cuando llamas por cuarta vez a la función `suma()` obtienes `[0,0,0]`

Comment: Cuando no se pasa argumento, la función "muta" el propio valor por defecto, lo que supone en la práctica que estás mutando el comportamiento mismo de la función.

Comment: No lo acabo de entender. En la tercera llamada haces `suma([1,2,3])` y modificas `lst=[0,0,0]` a `lst=[1,2,3,6]`. En la siguiente llamada no pasas argumento pero el valor de la lista es `lst=[1,2,3,6]` por lo que el resultado sería `lst=[1,2,3,6,12]`. ¿Dónde me pierdo?

Comment: El valor por defecto es un *atributo* de la función (`suma.__defaults__`) que se modifica cuando no pasas ningún argumento. Si pasas un argumento, será éste el que se modifique, no el valor por defecto.